# Generating a Webpage When It doesn't Exist

Tags: asp.net, url, webforms, asp.net-routing, generated-code

How can I generate a webpage based on users request? for example, If someone wants to visit "www.mywebsite.com/example" and there is no such url, My website will generate him/her a webpage based on word "example". How can I do it? (I'm developing my website by ASP.NET)

Comment: Have you considered using ASP.NET MVC, or are you limited to Web Forms?

Comment: I am limited to Web Forms.

Comment: You may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/asp.net-routing/info.

Answer (score -1):

One way to process such a page is to use ASP.NET attribute routing.

```
[Route("{pageName}")]
public ActionResults myActionName(String pageName)
{

// in this action method you process what you need to do to 

// figure out what you need to generate base to push to user.

//------

// either make a generic view and fill with your content or 

// generate the view code on the fly.

// you can also send view to user from a DB.

 return view();
}
```

for webforms check:
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668177(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: True. Routing can be used with Web Forms, but not like that.

Comment: @sushil  it is MVC, you can set the attribute routing for webforms as follow, but i haven't use webforms in the past 3 years. so i won't be able to comment. please check the following link [link to Microsoft routing page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668177(v=vs.140).aspx)

Comment: @Benjishk I meant the action result